# Oracle Trigger - update table B based on a condition of table A

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm attempting to create an Oracle trigger which sets the values of a column on table B based on a select statement run within the trigger.

I want to be able to set the values of the 'is_active' column in table B to 'N' based on the select statement after an insert on table A has been executed.

My query is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INACTIVE_STATE 
AFTER INSERT ON 
COMMENTS 
FOR EACH ROW  
DECLARE 
  inactive_id number;
BEGIN
  SELECT    distinct b.id 
  into    inactive_id
    from    comments a,
            modules b
    where   a.module_name=b.name
    and     a.type_id='FUNCTIONAL'
    and     a.module_id=b.id;
update  modules
set is_active='N'
where ID=:inactive_id
END INACTIVE_STATE;
/
```

When I try and complpile this trigger, I get the following errors:

```
Error(15,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(17,10): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'INACTIVE_ID'
Error(17,15): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
Error(19,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge
```

It seems it doesn't like the update statement, or the bind variable isn't being parsed within this process.

If I seperate these statements into 2 commands (using var to handle the bind variable :inactive_id) it works as expected.

```
VAR INACTIVE_ID number
begin
    select  distinct b.id into :INACTIVE_ID
    from    comments a,
            modules b
    where   a.module_name=b.name
    and     a.type_id='FUNCTIONAL'
    and     a.module_id=b.id;
    end;
    /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> update    modules
     set is_active='N'
     where ID=:INACTIVE_ID  
     /

    1 row updated.
```

Any ideas what I might be overlooking?

Comment: The trigger's where clause should be `where ID=inactive_id` - no colon.

Comment: Thanks Tony, the tigger compiled successfully!  However, when executing my update statement, I'm getting the following:  table COMMENTS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it   - any ideas how I deal with this?

Comment: First of all, what is the purpose of the select statement?  Is it really supposed to be looking at ALL comments, or this specific comment that you just inserted?  If all comments you should be able to remove the `FOR EACH ROW` and avoid the mutating issue.

Comment: Yep, that did it!  (end of the day, overlooked that one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tony Andrews pointed out in the comments of the original post, I was incorrectly using a colon before the "inactive_id" variable in the where clause.

The correct code should have been:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INACTIVE_STATE 
AFTER INSERT ON 
COMMENTS 
DECLARE 
  inactive_id number;
BEGIN
  SELECT    distinct b.id 
  into    inactive_id
    from    comments a,
            modules b
    where   a.module_name=b.name
    and     a.type_id='FUNCTIONAL'
    and     a.module_id=b.id;
update  modules
set is_active='N'
where ID=inactive_id
END INACTIVE_STATE;
/
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using

```
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
```

before begin

Comment: If trigger has DML statement and you want to commit the transaction; then without setting pragma autonomous, it will not allow you to do it. Basically, there is no hard and fast rule. whether to use pragma autonomous or not completely depends on the requirement.

Comment: OK, "99% of the time, don't do that"! The only valid case I can think of for it is if you for some reason want to log the action that fires the trigger, even if you then roll back the main transaction and it doesn't actually happen.  99% of the time you would just be potentially corrupting the database if you did this.